# Weird 'Missing $ inserted'

Tags: math-mode

The first screenshot is the formula. It is a part of my assignment. However, when I compile it, I got a lot of *Missing $ inserted* I cannot understand why. 
  Thank you!
[image: The formula]

[image: the information about the error]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please do not paste code as images, but as code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: when you use equation comand, I think that there is no need $ inside
P/S next time write the code instead of using an image :)

Comment: Don't use `$ ... $` constructs inside mathematical environments like `equation`, `align`, `gather`, &c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` shifts from text mode to math mode and back. `\begin{equation}` starts math mode, `R^i_t =` is fine. Then `$` ends math mode and enters text mode. Then `\alpha` is used in text mode and you get an error.

So change

```
\begin{equation}
  R^i_t = $\alpha$ + $\beta$R^M_t + $\mu$_t
\end{equation}
```

into

```
\begin{equation}
  R^i_t = \alpha + \beta R^M_t + \mu_t
\end{equation}
```